# Extract signals from CAN message using dbc-file without pre-compiled code?

Tags: networking, controller, signals, area, can-bus

I'm reading about extracting signals from CAN-messages using dbc-files. As far as I know, one needs to write (or auto-generate) specific code (e.g. for a microcontroller) for each dbc-file to be able to extract the signals from the CAN-messages. That implies that our code needs to be pre-compiled to understand the CAN-messages.

My question is: Is there a way to understand CAN-messages without pre-compiled code? For example by reading in a dbc-file and using the information of that dbc-file to understand the incoming CAN-messages?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This website is a brief overview of how to interpret DBC files through a text editor:

http://www.socialledge.com/sjsu/index.php?title=DBC_Format